# Simple unix shell loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

So I am very new to unix coding and I have a fairly simple task that I just can't seem to figure out.

I have a folder on my desktop with multiple `.fq` files (`Desktop/btindex`), and I am looking for a way to iterate over just those files in a shell script, and call commands on them.  I just can't seem to find the right syntax to do this.

Is it best to write this script in an editor like vim from the console?
Or is it better to just write it all out in the console itself?

Edit:
I am working in the directory Desktop/bwaout, so my code:

```
for file in '../btindex/*.fq';
do
    echo $file
done
```

seems to print...

```
../btindex/X.fq
```

How do I just get the .fq to print?

Comment: For your second question, I tend to write these scripts as one-liners in the console.  This lets me try out different versions until I get the result I want, then if it is something I will use again, copy the one-liner to a shell script and break it into multiple lines with proper indenting.

Comment: The single quotes around the expression in your code mean that the shell won't expand it into the list of files.  That's why it's echoing the `../btindex/X.fq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop as shown below:

```
for file in /some/path/*.fq
do
    echo "Processing file: $file"
    # other commands here    
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for myfile in *.fq ; do command "$myfile" ; another_command "$myfile" ; done
```

Comment: You should consistently use double quotes around variable interpolations which handle filenames; `"$myfile"`.